# Cant dismiss Popover UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I have a UITableViewController displayed as a popover as follows

```
    popoverViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemsTableView") as? ItemsTableViewController
    popoverViewController?.itemeSelectionDelegate = self
    popoverViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

    let popoverPresentationViewController = popoverViewController?.popoverPresentationController
    let itemCell  = cell as! ItemContentCell
    popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.any
    popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceView = cell
    popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceRect = itemCell.itemName.bounds

    present(popoverViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

popoverViewController is a member var, I am using it to dismiss when from popoverViewController an item is selected, I am calling a custom delegate method from which I am dismissing it using "Dismiss" method but it sometimes works sometimes it doesn't.

```
 func itemSelected(item: Item) {
    print("selected item")
    popoverViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Is there any other method to dismiss popover ?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint into `itemSelected:` to see if it is actually being called? And if so if `popoverViewController` is not nil at that time?

Comment: Yes it does get called and popoverViewController isn't nil

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` method `public func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool`.
Here is demo implementation.

```
    extension YouViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

        func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
    }
```